# Recommend place for google appengine launcher files to reside?

Tags: gnome, google

There is no launcher for google appengine like you have on the windows environs. However there is a [workaround](http://dejoe.tumblr.com/post/813391638/configure-google-app-engine-launcher-in-ubuntu-linux).

Problem is I copied everything to my `~/Downloads/google-appengine-launcher` folder. It worked okay. In the shell I just cd to the above path and do `./GoogleAppengineLauncher.py`; it works!!

But since that being a user specific folder I moved it to another generic location: `/usr/share/apps`, and I added a symbolic link to the above script as follows:

```
ln -s /usr/share/apps/google-appengine-launcher/GoogleAppengineLauncher.py /usr/bin/google-appengine-launcher
```

Now I do Alt+F2 to bring the Run dialog, and type in `google-appengine-launcher`, appengine application windows loads, but there is an error message saying it can't load icons...why is this so? How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no official way, but here is how I do it and it works out well...

This dir may already be created for you if you have Google Chrome installed. If not, lets create it then move the folder inside:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/google/
mv /usr/share/apps/google-appengine-launcher /opt/google
```

Now edit your `~/.bashrc` file and at the very bottom add:

```
export PATH=/opt/google/google-appengine-launcher:$PATH
```

Then run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

You may need to log out and back in for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to work (I'm not certain). But that should be all you need to do.

One last note, make sure and remove your symlink from before.

#### To have a simpler name as a start-up command:

Create an alias, shell function, a script, or a desktop shortcut.

For example, to create an alias, add this to `.bashrc`:

```
alias start_gae='GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py'
```

Then it's only necessary to enter `start_gae` at the shell prompt.

Comment: No. It didn't quite cut it. Now I have to type `GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py`. Wanted to type something shorter...

Comment: @deostroll An anonymous user has expanded this answer to include information about how you can set it up to avoid typing such a long command. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: @eliah-kagan Thanks. It was me. I can comment now. It's okay to ignore the additional edits I made, the UI was working against me and made it worst by not accepting my smaller corrections.